# Why does React Native/Objective-C complain that I call my method with the wrong number of arguments?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I am working on a React Native application using both Objective-C and Swift.

At the moment, I am trying to replace the current approach using EventEmitter with a more elegant solution using promises.

However, I have some troubles because I get a complaint from the compiler/interpreter that I am calling my method with the wrong number of arguments:

`ExceptionsManager.js:71 RecorderBridge.startRecording was called with 0 arguments but expects 1 arguments. If you haven't changed this method yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.`

However, I actually do not have any arguments, except resolver and rejecter which should not be complaint about by the compiler/interpreter.

My code looks as follows:

**Recorder.js**

```
...
startRecording = () => {
  RecorderNative.startRecording();
};
...
```

**RecorderNativeModule.js**

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { RecorderBridge } = NativeModules;

export default {
  startRecording() {
    return RecorderBridge.startRecording();
  }
}
```

**RecorderBridge.m**

```
@implementation RecorderBridge 
  ...
  RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startRecording: resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    BOOL result = [myRecorderViewController startRecording];

    if (result) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  }
 ...
@end
```

**RecorderController.swift**

```
@objc open class RecorderViewController : UIViewController {
  @objc func startRecording() -> Bool {
    do {
      // Try to start recording
      try recorder.record();
      return true
    } catch {
      print("Errored recording.")
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with your exported method syntax, you actually are sort of requiring a parameter but you don't get an error because it is passed to the RN macro. In Objective-C you don't label the first parameter.

Instead of this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startRecording: resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

It should look like this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startRecording:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

Comment: How would this look if I have a different argument like NSDictionary for the first argument? Thanks!

Comment: The first argument is handled exactly as the above example. The first parameter is just not labeled. In this example, if you want the first argument to be a `NSDictionary`, you can change it like so: `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startRecording:(NSDictionary*)params resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)`